# Get keys from dict using list comprehention

Tags: python

I have a list and dict in python say,
`list A = [1, 3]`
`dict B = {'apple':1, 'orange':3, 'carrot': 4}`
so now I want to use list comprehension in python and get the list of keys with 'values' in list A.

Comment: You realize you are running the dictionary "in reverse" right?

Answer (score 1):

First you would need to loop through the dictionary, then check if the value is in the other list.
This can be done with or without list-comprehension.

Using list-comprehension:

```
value = [x for x in B if B[x] in A]
```

Without list-comprehension:

```
value = []
for x in B:
    if B[x] in A:
        value.append(x)
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

```
a = set([1,3])
b = {'apple':1, 'orange':3, 'carrot': 4} 

# Filter dict b with a as keys
c = {k:v for k,v in b.items() if k in a}
```

Comment: `list(c.keys())` for the list of keys, correction should be `v in a`

Comment: Also, convert list a to `set(a)` to bring down the time complexity of `in` operation

Answer (score 0):

This small list comprehension should do.

```py
a = [1,3]
b = {'apple':1, 'orange':3, 'carrot': 4}
print([x for x in b if b[x] in a])
```